# Change x and y position of UIScrollview dynamically in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have used UIScrollView named "scrMainView".
I have defined its property in .xib file as x=0, y=260, width=320, height=1860.

So now Button click event, I want scrollview up. ie. y=80. rest of parameters remain as it is.

I have used code :

```
[scrMainView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,-180, 320, 2800) animated:NO];

scrMainView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -180);
```

I have used either of both lines. But it give same output as it focuses scrollview.
But I want to change Y position. So ScrollView appears more upside on screen area.

I have defined in property in .xib already. So will this effect on dynamic code..?

Any Solution..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `frame` property of the UIScrollView.

```
scrMainView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change following line with frame instead of contentOffset:

```
scrMainView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y, 320,2800);
```

Comment: `scrMainView.scrollEnabled = YES;`. Did you try this..?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for disabled ScrollView.

I have used code for set Content Size again.

ie. scrMainView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 3600);

So, its working with dynamically changing x, y and scrolling too.

Answer (score 0):

swift3

```
scrMainView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -180, width: 320, height: 2800)
```